# How to Calculate battery drainage from a set # of LEDs

Tags: voltage, batteries, parallel

I will be wiring 18 LEDs to three 3.7V batteries(600mAh) in parallel. 10 of the LEDs are rated at 4.5V with 40mA and 8 LEDs are rated 3V with 20mA, how long will these 18 LEDs run on the three batteries before dying?

Comment: If the batteries are connected in parallel you will only get 3.7V which is less than the voltage required to drive the 4.5V LEDs.

Comment: A schematic would be of great help.

Comment: Attempting to drive that bunch of 4.5V 40mA LEDs directly from 3.7V cells connected in parallel would count as felony *assault on battery*.

Answer (score 2):

If the LEDs are connected in series, then the battery will last pretty close to its shelf life, since very little current will flow.  18 LEDs in series will need way more than 3.7 V to have any significant current thru them.

If the LEDs are wired in parallel, then it is impossible to tell from your description.  The 10 LEDs that apparently need 4.5 V to light up appreciably (are you sure that is right, sounds very high, even for blue or white LEDs) won't do anything because the 8 LEDs that will each draw around 20 mA at 3 V will prevent the voltage from going much higher than that.  It then becomes a fight between the LEDs that want to drag the voltage down to 3 V, and the batteries that will try to keep it at 3.7 V.

Small 600 mAh cells probably have significant internal resistance, and the LED current will go up rapidly with small increases in voltage.  All this means the voltage will be held to around 3 V or a little more, with the LEDs taking whatever is needed to hold the batteries that low.  Since we don't know what the internal resistance of the batteries is or what their short-circuit current is, there is no way to know the current.  The capacity of the battery is also not much help even if we did know the current since the current will likely be high enough to be battery abuse.  That means the batteries will put out less than their rating, probably significantly less.  If they can supply a lot of current without significant degradation, then the LEDs will get abused.

There is just too little information here to provide a meaningful answer.